# How to make only MPMoviePlayerController in both landscape and portrait mode

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, uideviceorientation

I am working on a application which has to play videos when clicking on some thumbnail, I am displaying list. I want only the Video to rotate in Landscape and Portrait Mode but other screens must in Portrait Mode How can we do this.

Comment: In which iOS version?

Comment: I want this to be implemented in iOS 5,6

Answer (score 0):

In ViewWillAppear

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:NULL];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
```

This will trigger the redrawing of the view and thus calling following functions, provided you have implemented these

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```