# UIDeviceOrientation for MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, uideviceorientation

I am working on a app in which I have a list of items where i want to click on a thumbnail and video must be played, My requirement is Only MPMovieViewController must rotate remaining screens must not rotate for this I am using below method in list to make it portrait every time. But if i am using it i am not able to rotate the MPMoviePlayerViewController.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

So i returned "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll" after returning i am able to Autorotate the MPMoviePlayerViewController But when i come back clicking on done Button or after video is done when video is in landscape mode then my previous is rotating but i dont want that behaviour i need the previous view in portrait, Below is code for implementing the MPMoviePlayerViewContoller.

```
    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[exeDict objectForKey:@"longVideoName"] ofType:@"mp4"];

    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayerController.moviePlayer];

    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    moviePlayerController.view.userInteractionEnabled =YES;

    [moviePlayerController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll];

//    AppDelegate* myDelegate = (((AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate));
//    [myDelegate.window addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];

    MainViewController* mainViewController = (MainViewController*)self.mainViewDelegate;

    [mainViewController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer play];
```

Please let me know how to get it.

Comment: This question might be a duplicate of [How to make only MPMoviePlayerController in both landscape and potrait mode][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143945/how-to-make-only-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-both-landscape-and-potrait-mode

Comment: That Answer didnt help :(

Answer (score 0):

you will have have to put code in viewwillappear() method so that your list appears in portrait mode

Comment: this had helped me that's why i suggested this otherwise Aʌɐpɥɐuı, u suggest a answer, i will also accept that if it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

Implemented above code in mainViewController??